# How to wait for all promises to resolve in Google Client Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise, google-analytics-api

I'm using [Google Analytics Management API for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js) to access Google Analytics.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. load filters from all accounts (an array of ids).
2. delete all loaded filters (from loaded accounts).
3. after all delete operation are done: add new filters to all accounts.
4. after all add operation are done: show done message.

I get into trouble with points 3 and 4. I'm not able to wait for a list of promises to finish before for any further.

The semi pseudo-code is as follows, and I don't have `waitForAllPromises(listOfPromises)` :)

```
var promises = [];
for(accountId in accountIds) {
    (function(accountId){
        promise = 
            loadAccountFilters(accountId) // returns gapi.client.analytics....then()
                .then(function(){
                    deleteAccountFilters(accountId); // returns gapi.client.analytics....then()
                });
        promises.push(promise);
    })(accountId);
}

waitForAllPromises(promises)
    .then(function(){
        console.log('All delete operation done.');

        var promises = [];
        for(accountId in accountIds) {
            (function(accountId){
                promise = addNewFilters(accountId); // returns gapi.client.analytics....then()
            })(accountId);
        }
        promises.push(promise);

        waitForAllPromises(promises)
        .then(function(){
            console.log('All add operation done.');
        });
    });
```

I only have access to Google Client Library and jQuery, but it seems `$.when.apply($,promises).then(...)` from jQuery, which can wait for all promises to resolve, doesn't work with GCL promise objects.

Comment: Can "$http.pendingRequests.length !== 0;" help you in checking if all promises are returned or not?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a [batch request](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises#batch-requests)? Alternatively, calling `$.when(promise)` on a single promise should create a jQuery deferred that is compatible with the `$.when` array call.

Comment: `$.when(googleRequestPromise)` doesn't work like a jQueryPromise. At least I don't get it to work. 

I don't get `batch request` to work with nested `.then` calls, like `.req.then(...).then( ...req2.then()... )`.

Answer (score 0):

Never head about Promise/$q? Your logic is good! You should replace Promise.all/$q.all with `waitForAllPromises`

```
var promises = [];
for(accountId in accountIds) {
    (function(accountId){
        promise = 
            loadAccountFilters(accountId) // returns gapi.client.analytics....then()
                .then(function(){
                    deleteAccountFilters(accountId); // returns gapi.client.analytics....then()
                });
        promises.push(promise);
    })(accountId);
}

Promise.all(promises) 
    .then(function(outputs) {
        console.log('All delete operation done.');

        var promises = [];
        for(accountId in accountIds) {
            (function(accountId){
                promise = addNewFilters(accountId); // returns gapi.client.analytics....then()
            })(accountId);
        }
        promises.push(promise);

        Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function() {
            console.log('All add operation done.');
        });
    });
```